# What happens when I assign an out-of-range value to a short int in C?

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion, narrowing

I know the range of `short` is from `32767` to `-32768` on most systems. But when I try to assign `32787` I see something different.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   short int a;
   a = 32787;
   printf("%hi\n",a);
}
```

Output:

```
-32749
```

This value actually **my value + minimum short value + minimum short value** and not some random value. `(32787 + (-32768)) + (-32768) = -32749`

This is the first case I try to assign a high value to short int I will get warning from GCC I get some value.

This makes the results completely incomprehensible. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `Which makes the results completely incomprehensible. Does anyone know what's going on here?` - what do you mean by this? You have more test cases?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you did in your second case, that made the results "completely incomprehensible"? This is technically implementation defined behavior (prior to C2x) but you should normally observe behavior consistent with your first case.